# What does x?.y?.z mean?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

The draft spec for [Pattern Matching in C#](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4558A04E77D0CF5%215396) contains the following code example:

```
Type? v = x?.y?.z; 
if (v.HasValue) {
    var value = v.GetValueOrDefault();     
    // code using value 
}
```

I understand that `Type?` indicates that `Type` is nullable, but assuming `x`, `y`, and `z` are locals, what does `x?.y?.z` mean?

Comment: nullcheck i assume..

Comment: Does anyone have another link for that "Pattern Matching in C#" draft spec, that isn't on a MSN OneDrive?  The link is broken behind some corporate proxies. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does question mark and dot operator ?. mean in C# 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Be aware that this language feature is only available in C# 6 and later.**

It's effectively the equivalent of:

```
x == null ? null
   : x.y == null ? null
   : x.y.z
```

In other words, it's a "safe" way to do `x.y.z`, where any of the properties along the way might be null.

Also related is the [null coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), which provides values to substitute for `null`.

Comment: I've been waiting for this for ages

Comment: It's worth noting that x.y will only be evaluated once using the new syntax but twice using the current equivalent (assuming x and x.y are non-null).

Comment: The indentation makes your answer difficult to read. I for one would indent the colon on the same column as the matching question mark.

Comment: @Kay: If that's how the style guide works chez vous, you're welcome to do it however you want. :-)

Comment: So when can Java programmers expect this sort of functionality?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight it's not scheduled for java 8 and java 9, so I guess in like next 10 years.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I actually asked one of my coworkers about this; it was apparently suggested for Java 6 or 7 but Oracle said "No, we can't make language-level changes" ind introduced the [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class as an alternative.  Suffice it to say that it's nowhere near as nice as being able to just use `x?.y?.z;`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Although `Optional.flatMap` isn't as nice as `x?.y?.z`, it sure is nice to not have the code blow up in random places because `null` was being passed around. So I guess it depends on what you consider nicer.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight, only using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28?.%29), which, i think, created it, but i have no backing resources to it. Otherwise, Optional on [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) or [Scala](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_options.htm)

Comment: @Doval, Actually, I think the *best* thing would have been if reference types weren't allowed to be null in the first place, unless you added a `Nullable<>` around them. I agree, though, about how nice it is to avoid null reference exceptions. I even created a library, [Call Me Maybe](https://bitbucket.org/j2jensen/callmemaybe) to provide an equivalent of `Optional` for C#. Point being, I think the language feature and an `Optional` type can complement each other--they shouldn't be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Agreed. Seems like an awful lot of work for something so specific though. You could get much more mileage out of something like Haskell's *do notation*.

Comment: I wonder how useful would it be to implement something like this to ECMAscript. I wouldn't say no to having something like this in JS.

Comment: var exclamation = THIS?.Is?.SPARTA;

Comment: var nonNullableInt = x?.y?.z ?? 0;

Answer (score 29):

It is [Null-propagating operator / Null-Conditional Operator ?.](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883) a new proposed feature in C# 6.0

`x?.y?.z` means

- first, check if `x` is not null, then **check** `y` otherwise return null,
- second,  when x is not null then check `y`, if it is not null then return `z` otherwise return null.

The ultimate return value will be `z` or `null`.

Without this operator if `x` is null, then accessing `x.y` would raise a Null Reference Exception, the Null-Conditional operator helps to avoid explicitly checking for null.

It is a way to avoid Null Reference Exception.

See: [Getting a sense of the upcoming language features in C#](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552378)

> **8 - Null-conditional operators**
>
> Sometimes code tends to drown a bit in null-checking. The
>   null-conditional operator lets you access  members and elements only
>   when the receiver is not-null, providing a null result otherwise:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null
```

Comment: I'd add that this is a C# 6 feature.

Comment: @tkocmathla Nope, `??` is quite different: `x ?? y` is like `x != null ? x : y`. And `x?.y` is like `x != null ? x.y : null`.

Comment: @Habib Its still wrong "if x is not null, return y otherwise return null,". This does not return y, it either returns x.y.z or null.

Comment: @mclaassen, may be I am explaining considering them two different steps. The ultimate return value would be either `z` or `null`

Answer (score 3):

```
 this.SlimShadies.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IsTheReal)?.PleaseStandUp();
```

Basically.