# What does question mark and dot operator ?. mean in C# 6.0?

Tags: c#, operators, c#-6.0

With C# 6.0 in the VS2015 preview we have a new operator, **`?.`**, which can be used like this:

```cs
public class A {
   string PropertyOfA { get; set; }
}

...

var a = new A();
var foo = "bar";
if(a?.PropertyOfA != foo) {
   //somecode
}
```

What exactly does it do?

Comment: If you are intersted in coverting a nullable bool `bool ?` into a `bool` value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075726/convert-nullable-bool-to-bool

Answer (score 769, accepted):

It's the [*null conditional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator. It basically means:

"Evaluate the first operand; if that's null, stop, with a result of null. Otherwise, evaluate the second operand (as a member access of the first operand)."

In your example, the point is that if `a` is `null`, then `a?.PropertyOfA` will evaluate to `null` rather than throwing an exception - it will then compare that `null` reference with `foo` (using string's `==` overload), find they're not equal and execution will go into the body of the `if` statement.

In other words, it's like this:

```
string bar = (a == null ? null : a.PropertyOfA);
if (bar != foo)
{
    ...
}
```

... except that `a` is only evaluated once.

Note that this can change the type of the expression, too. For example, consider [`FileInfo.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length). That's a property of type `long`, but if you use it with the null conditional operator, you end up with an expression of type `long?`:

```
FileInfo fi = ...; // fi could be null
long? length = fi?.Length; // If fi is null, length will be null
```

Comment: @SLaks: I thought it was "conditional null" but I could be wrong. Last time I checked the Roslyn language features docs, it hadn't been renamed to either. Maybe the source is the authority here - will check.

Comment: "conditional null" makes it sound like it's a kind of null, which it isn't.

Comment: @SLaks: Sure. In SyntaxKind it's apparently ConditionalAccessExpression which is annoyingly neither of them...

Comment: @SLaks: Have asked Pilchie :)

Comment: If the OP's example `if(a ?. PropertyOfA != foo)` is valid then your answer implies that `if(null)` is also valid. Is it, and if so, does it evaluate to `true` or `false`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: No, it's only the `a?.PropertyOfA` that evaluates to null - I'll make that clear.

Comment: i preferred the name "Elvis" operator :P

Comment: Just for the record I've seen five different names for this operator: safe navigation, null-conditional, null propagation, conditional access, Elvis.

Comment: Even on the highest warning level, with warnings as error, the Microsoft compiler will allow the "unsafe" code. Mono on the other hand will throw an error and call for an explicit cast. This is just a hint for everyone getting `CS0019` in Mono on code that compiles fine with .NET.

Comment: @mınxomaτ: Which "unsafe" code are you talking about?

Comment: @JonSkeet Not really unsafe (hence the quotemarks). It's about your note about suddenly changing types. Mono users frequently encounter error messages such as `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.` when building code that contains `?.` No such error is generated with .NET's compiler (which is not a problem).

Comment: Old question, but this doesn't warrant its own: Is there a way to use this for a case like `string.Join(",", potentiallyNull)`, or should I just stick to using the ternary operator?

Comment: @Sinjai maybe `potentiallyNull ?? ""`

Comment: @Gabriel Yeah but what about when it's not null. Then I want to do the `string.Join()` function. I don't see a way around ternary, I was just wondering if there was someone more clever than myself who knew some sort of magic.

Comment: If you do `string.Join(",", potentiallyNull ?? "")` and `potentiallyNull` is null, then `string.Join` returns an empty string. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I think "safe evaluation" would be the best to describe this operator. It makes sure you don't evaluate properties or methods of a null object because then you get all those nasty errors. The bad is that "it hides" the problem why the Object is null because mostly it was not intended to be null. So it should be used with that in mind.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom: Well an *object* is never null to start with... I'd be happy with "null-safe dereferencing" but "safe evaluation" sounds a bit too broad to me. I think it's best to stick to the language specification terminology though: the null conditional operator.

Comment: The expression object?.x is safe evaluated because it does not throws a error because object does not have a value. With an object is null I meant the object is declared but does not have a value.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom: Again, that terminology is incorrect - it's the *variable* that's declared, and the variable has a value of null. But consider `x?.Foo(10)` - is that "safe evaluation"? Sure, it won't throw a null reference exception immediately if `x` is null, but it could easily still throw an exception. It could even throw a NullReferenceException, inside `Foo`. It's only the dereferencing of x that's null-safe, hence my suggested terminology if you really, really don't want to use what the C# team has decided on.

Comment: Ok for my purpose I consider the whole expression as "safe evaluation" and I know only the x? part plays a role in this. The "safe" is because its done at run-time. The Foo(10) part is not interesting to me because I already made sure that works at compile-time.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I definitely don't think "safe evaluation" is as clear and precise as either "null-safe dereferencing" or "the null conditional operator".

Comment: It‘s simply syntactic sugar for binding field / property access or a method call as a function to its left hand side argument, interpreting that as a monoid in a category of endofunctors.

Comment: Useful to note... you can also use the null conditional on arrays, like: a?[x]

Answer (score 143):

It can be very useful when flattening a hierarchy and/or mapping objects.  Instead of:

```
if (Model.Model2 == null
  || Model.Model2.Model3 == null
  || Model.Model2.Model3.Model4 == null
  || Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name == null)
{
  mapped.Name = "N/A"
}
else
{
  mapped.Name = Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name;
}
```

It can be written like (same logic as above)

```
mapped.Name = Model.Model2?.Model3?.Model4?.Name ?? "N/A";
```

[DotNetFiddle.Net Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TrsnYh).

(the [?? or null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) is different than the [? or null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)).

It can also be used out side of assignment operators with Action.  Instead of

```
Action<TValue> myAction = null;

if (myAction != null)
{
  myAction(TValue);
}
```

It can be simplified to:

```
myAction?.Invoke(TValue);
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1jUwEP):

using System;

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Action<string> consoleWrite = null;
    
    consoleWrite?.Invoke("Test 1");
    
    consoleWrite = (s) => Console.WriteLine(s);
    
    consoleWrite?.Invoke("Test 2");
  }
}
```

Result:

> Test 2

> Basically, I have applied ?. operator after Model as well. I am trying to know that whether it can be applied directly to the model or does it only work with the navigation properties?

The [? or null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operators on the left value, regardless of the type of value. And the compiler doesn't care what the value is on the right.  It's simple compiler *magic* (meaning it does something you can already do, just in a simplified why).

For example

```
  var a = model?.Value;
```

is the same as saying

```
  var a = model == null ? null : model.Value;
```

In the second case the evaluation of checking for null has no associate with the value returned.  The *null conditional operator* basically just always return null if the left value is null.

The type of member (Method, Field, Property, Constructor)  `.Value` is irrelevant.

The reason your DotNetFiddle example doesn't work is because the compiler being use for the `.Net 4.7.2` isn't compatible with the c# version that support the null conditional operator.  Changing it to .Net 5, works:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7EWoO5

Comment: To save people looking up what the ?? is.. It is the null-coalescing operator and will return Name if it is not null, otherwise it will return "N/A".

Comment: @Erik Philips I think you need to add   
       **`|| Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name == null`**  

to have  the same logic, otherwise in case `Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name` is `null`, `mapped.Name` will stay `null`

Comment: @ErikPhilips Not on the same page I guess. 
 Please try to see what happens in both your cases if `Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name` is `null`.

Comment: The result is "N/A", again PLEASE READ THE FIRST COMMENT.  [DotNetFiddle.Net Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TrsnYh).

Comment: @ErikPhilips: That has nothing to to with the first comment, as this does not relate to your first example. In this you would jump into the `else`-branch and have `mapped.Name = Model.Model2.Model3.Model4.Name -> mapped.Name = null`, while you second example would substitute to `mapped.Name = "N/A"`. See the [edited DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vunRkC)

Comment: Would this work: `mapped.Name = Model?.Model2?.Model3?.Model4?.Name ?? "N/A";`. Basically, I have applied `?.` operator after `Model` as well. I am trying to know that whether it can be applied directly to the model or does it only work with the navigation properties? Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2BblBv

Comment: @Junaid I've updated the question, let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 10):

This is relatively new to C# which makes it easy for us to call the functions with respect to the *null or non-null* values in method chaining.

old way to achieve the same thing was:

```
var functionCaller = this.member;
if (functionCaller!= null)
    functionCaller.someFunction(var someParam);
```

and now it has been made much easier with just:

```
member?.someFunction(var someParam);
```

I strongly recommend [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Comment: Quick question..`var user = db.Users.Where(m=>m.id == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
Console.WriteLine(user?.id);` Would this work or `?.` only work with navigation properties? Kindly check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2BblBv

Comment: The above answer basically states this, but just for emphasis, "functionCaller" here could be "object that could have associated methods", so, if there was a `cat` object that has a `meow()` method, if you want to check to see whether `cat` is null prior to invoking `meow()`, then code it up as `cat?.meow()`.  If `cat` is currently null, `meow()` will not be invoked.