# if else conditional implementation c#

Tags: c#

I want to create an if/else statement in this case :

```
        var controls= _listControls
            .Select(
                control => new
                {
                    Name,
                    Quantity,
                    Valid = isValid
                    ? sp.GetInfos(ID).SerialNumber.ToString()
                    : string.Empty
                })
            .ToList();
```

I just want to check if `sp.GetInfos(ID).SerialNumber.ToString()`is null in the statement and say if `it's not null ? DoThings() : DoThings()` .

Thanks

Comment: How to make simple statement unreadable? Put it into one-liner and split it into multiple liines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operators **inside** other ternary statements like this

```
Valid = isValid
? string.IsNullOrEmpty(sp.GetInfos(ID).SerialNumber?.ToString())
? string.Empty 
: sp.GetInfos(ID).SerialNumber.ToString()
: string.Empty
```

**N.B.** The `SerialNumber?.ToString()` is a null conditional operator, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0)

Comment: you can replace lines 2-3 with `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: ToString() will never return null. But if SerialNumber is null a NullReferenceException will be thrown.

Comment: I have edited the code so that if SerialNumber is null, null is returned but otherwise it is turned into a string

Comment: this violate the principle: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live." ( cit )

Comment: While this is true and I agree to an extent as an if would be better here, the OP asked specifically for the answer using ternary, I can add a second version with if statements if you would like, or point to Valentin's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate all logic in a helper method. As I consider it's more readable and also you are able to test this method separately.

```
string Valid(....)
{
    if (isValid)
    {
        if (sp.GetInfos(ID).SerialNumber == null)
        {
            ....
        }
        else
        {
            ..
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

And then simply call this method inside LINQ query

```
var controls = _listControls
        .Select(
            control => new
            {
                Name,
                Quantity,
                Valid = Valid (...) 
            })
        .ToList();
```