# What does the question mark operator mean in C#?

Tags: c#

First off, I already know about ternary statements.  However, I recently saw a piece of code like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Result result)
{
    return result?.Actions?.Utterance;
}
```

What is the question mark operator used for here?

Comment: Better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0 (which is also the second result when you google for `c# question mark operator`)

Comment: How is asking what the null conditional operator is a duplicate of asking what the equivalent of the null conditional operator is in javascript?

Comment: People would not google on the already answered question. So the answer is: 
`If a evaluates to null, the result of a?.x or a?[x] is null.` and
`If a evaluates to non-null, the result of a?.x or a?[x] is the same as the result of a.x or a[x], respectively.`

Answer (score 0):

This is the [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator:

> Used to test for null before performing a member access (?.) or index
>   (?[) operation.

You method's code without the use of null conditional operator it could be written as below:

```
public void DoSomething(Result result)
{
    if(result!=null)
    {
        if(result.Actions!=null)
        {
            return result.Actions.Utterance;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This operator is the short form for an null conditional if statement:

```
public void DoSomething(Result result)
{
    if(result != null){
        if(result.Actions != null){
            return result.Actions.Utterance;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```