# Prevent C# exception and find more elegant way to make check for nullable value

Tags: c#, exception, logic, conditional-statements

```
CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate.HasValue ? meta.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString : null
```

This line of code throws exception 'Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between method group and null.'

Is there any working way to make this check and and/or any more elegant (less ugly) way?

Note:

```
myObject = (dynamic)new
{
    CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate.HasValue ? meta.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString : null
}
```

Comment: `meta.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString` is a method group. `meta.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()` is how to call the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does question mark and dot operator ?. mean in C# 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0)

Comment: @SeM - No, it's not. The issue here is that the OP missed putting the `()` at the end of his method call. He's not asking about the dot operator at all.

Comment: The code doesn't throw an exception - it doesn't compile and hence can't throw an exception.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's for "more elegant way to check for null"

Comment: @SeM - Yes, it is, but that not asking what the `?.` operator does. It's a different question, but around the same topic.

Comment: Ops, yes i forget the braces, thanks y'all. Any more elegant way anyway :) ??

Comment: Thank you all. And probably i've learned my lesson again (for 1000th time) - if you sleepy and exhausted - coffee brake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the calling braces `()` for method call it should be `ToShortDateString()` as for calling a method we need those so, your code line should look like:

```
CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate.HasValue ? meta.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString() : null ;
```

But If you are using C# 6 you can do following via null propagation operator:

```
String CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate?.ToShortDateString();
```

or:

```
String CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate?.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

and if you are below C# 6 then try :

```
String CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate.HasValue ? meta.CreatedDate..ToShortDateString() ? null;
```

Comment: You should point out that `.ToShortDateString` is a method group & `.ToShortDateString()` is how to call a method.

Comment: just noted that and was updating post

Answer (score 2):

You can use the null-conditional operator:

```
CreatedDate = meta.CreatedDate?.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: You should fix your code: `.ToShortDateString` is a method group. `.ToShortDateString()` is how to call a method.