# C# Linq statement for each

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write the following statement:

```
things.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.thingname = x.thingname.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
    x.thingname2 = x.thingname2.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
});
```

This code works fine and replace works successfully.  However if `x.thingname` is null the code errors.  How can I check for null values before doing the replace?

Comment: `if (x.thingname != null) { x.thingname = ... }`? Or alternatively `x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace(...)` using C# 6.0's [null conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace(....) gives me syntax errors?...

Comment: @cbr if `?.` gives a syntax error, you're probably using an older compiler - that syntax is relatively new (C# 6). So if that isn't an option, use `if(x.thingname != null) { ... }` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can try like this , [`?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?. and ?[] null-conditional Operators`)  (it has nothing to do with linq , you code is ok just put `?` as suggested  )

```
 x.thingname =  x.thingname?.Replace("oldvalue",  "newvalue");
```

and you code will be like this

```
things.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace("oldvalue",      "newvalue");
    x.thingname2 = x.thingname2?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

that isn't LINQ - it is just lambdas

If you want to check whether something is null: *check whether it is null*.

```
if  (x.thingname != null) { ... }
```

would work, although the inline null check would work too:

```
x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
x.thingname2 = x.thingname2?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
```

However, the `ToList().ForEach()` here is unnecessary and expensive. Just use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var x in things) {
    x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
    x.thingname2 = x.thingname2?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
}
```

Comment: you dont need x?. as x must be there , otherwise it will throw execption in first go it self

Comment: @PranayRana you're right - I typo'd; fixed

Comment: just want to know `ToList().ForEach()` slow down performance ??

Comment: @PranayRana well, yes! `ToList()` allocates a new list, iterates (`foreach`) over the source, appends to the new list (perhaps resizing it multiple times), and returns the new list - that's a lot of work! Then `ForEach` iterates over the new list, and requires a delegate allocation first (although that might be reused in some cases). It also precludes the possibility of using a custom duck-typed iterator, which several types provide, and which is especially cheap. So yeah, there are *tons* of ways that this make this **much** more expensive than just a simple `foreach` over the original data.

Comment: thanks it helps ...i think you should include in answer too that will help readers ..

Comment: @PranayRana meh, it is here

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator:

```
things.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.thingname = x.thingname?.Replace("oldvalue",      "newvalue");
    x.thingname2 = x.thingname2?.Replace("oldvalue", "newvalue");
});
```