# How do I ignore null reference exceptions with Set-StrictMode?

Tags: powershell

Trying to use native powershell way to assign null value to variable which can not be resolved. My understanding if I set `Set-StrictMode -Off` I shall be able to do something like below but it fails. Is there a way to tell powershell engine that in case exception is thrown just assign `$null` to result and don't show any exceptions without `if` statement

```
PS C:\Users\a> $item = $string.NonExistentmember.Split("/")
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $item = $string.NonExistentmember.Split("/")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Umm... no. PowerShell will expand non-existent values/properties to empty values alright, but that doesn't mean you can call a (non-existing) method on such an empty value. In this particular case you could dodge the error by using the `-split` operator instead of the `Split()` method, but good practice is to not expect the runtime to gloss over such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't related to strict mode (which is off by default anyway). You're looking more for something like [C#'s null conditional operator `?.`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28352072/3905079), which would let you do

```
$string?.NonExistentmember?.Split("/")
```

if it existed in PowerShell, which it unfortunately doesn't.
(However, its introduction is being discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3240).)

You can use the split operator like Ansgars suggested in a comment:

```
$string.NonExistentmember -split "/"
```

But do note that they don't work exactly the same (the operator uses regex, the method uses `char`s).