# Blazor modifying a string (toUpper) fails

Tags: webassembly, blazor

I'm doing some testing with Blazor and wanted to take a string and simply change it to uppercase as follows:

```
@page "/InputBindingTest"
<h1>Binding examples...</h1>
<hr />

<h2>Text input example:</h2>
<p>Firing the 'oninput' event for each key press</p>

<input type="text" bind-value-oninput="@CurrentText" />

<p>Current value is: @CurrentText</p>

<p>Here it is again in UPPERCASE: @CurrentText.ToUpper()</p>

<h2>Checkbox example:</h2>
<input name="check1" type="checkbox" bind-value-onchange="@CurrentSetting" />
<label for="check1">@CurrentSetting</label>

@functions {
    private string CurrentText { get; set; }
    private bool CurrentSetting { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works except the ToUpper method on the string. Web Assembly takes a nasty dive:

> WASM: Unhandled exception rendering component

I suppose this can't be done (yet) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A careful look at the generated error trace reveals this is about a null reference exception.

The simple fix is a `?.` :

```
<p>Here it is again in UPPERCASE: @CurrentText?.ToUpper()</p>
```

and/or

```
private string CurrentText { get; set; } = "";
```

Blazor's binding can handle a `null` in `@CurrentText</p>` just fine.
But `ToUpper()` can't be called on a null string.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0 for the null conditional operator for the very useful ?.

Comment: Thanks @Henk. I forgot about that operator and didn't think to use it but it makes perfect sense in this case as we don't have any input to apply the method to.