# Async function that queries data from Entity Framework

Tags: .net, async-await, entity-framework-core

I created this function and I am not sure that it is the best way to create an asynchronous function that gets data from entity framework:

```
public async Task<Employe?> EmployeToConnect(string login, string password)
    {
        Employe? employeResult = null;
        employeResult = await _context.Employes.FirstOrDefaultAsync
         (empl => empl.Login == login && empl.Password == password);
        return employeResult;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it?
(Seeing that the inspected returned type is **Task< Employe>** and we just returned **Employe?** )

Comment: It seems an opinion-based question, but if you want to  learn about `?` you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352116/6691714

Comment: More than anything else your question is [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293/861716).

Answer (score 0):

The return type will still be a `Task<Employee?>`. Due to the `async` keyword the result of `EmployeToConnect` will be wrapped in a task. You could also avoid the async keyword and return the task directly, but this will affect how the exception handling works (although it would mean a very minor performance benefit).

- Due to the `async` keyword, the result of `EmployeToConnect` will be wrapped into its own new task, which in turn awaits the underlying task from `FirstOrDefaultAsync`
- Without the `async` keyword, you could also directly return the task from `FirstOrDefaultAsync`(without awaiting it due to `await` only being usable in an async method)